# SQL/SQLAlchemy filter on previously limited results

Tags: python, join, filter, sqlalchemy, limit

I have to filter my products by the status name. I have a subquery to get the last status for each product (the last status is the only one relevant for my usecase).

I want to get `Product` whose last status matches a list of status names (`statuses` in my example).

Models:

```py
class Product(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "products"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    statuses = relationship("Status", back_populates="product")

class Status(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "status"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=functions.now(), index=True)
```

Query:

```py
subquery = (
    select(Status.id)
    .filter(
        Status.product_id == Product.id,
    )
    .order_by(Status.created_at.desc())
    .limit(1)
    .correlate(Status)
    .subquery()
)
```

I want to filter on status names with the following code:

```
statement = (
    select(Product.id)
    .outerjoin(Status)
    .filter(
        Status.id.in_(subquery),
        Status.name.in_(statuses),
    )
)
```

But unfortunately, I got products with the last status not matching my `statuses`.

I think this is because I wrote my SQLAlchemy request like

> Give me products with status matching the `statuses`

and it looks to the last status matching the `statuses`,
instead of

> Give me products with **THE LAST** status matching the `statuses`

for it to look to the last status **AND** check if this status match the `statuses`.

Why this result?

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option-1:** One way would be to add a `JOIN` with the filter which will select only the latest `Status`:

```py
query = (
    select(Product)

    .innerjoin(
        Status,
        Status.id == (
            select(Status.id)
            .filter(Status.product_id == Product.id)
            .order_by(Status.created_at.desc())
            .limit(1)
            .scalar_subquery()
            .correlate(Product)
        )
    )

    .filter(Status.name.in_(statuses))
)
```

**Option-2:** Add `computed_column` for `last_status_name`

First, add this property to the `Product`:

```py
Product.last_status_name = column_property(
    select(Status.name.label("last_status_name"))
    .filter(Status.product_id == Product.id)
    .order_by(Status.created_at.desc())
    .limit(1)
    .scalar_subquery(),
    deferred=True  # prevent from always loading this from the database
)
```

Then you can use it whenever you need to simply by adding a filter to a query:

```py
query = (
    select(Product)
    .filter(Product.last_status_name.in_(statuses))
)
```

*And if you remote the `deferred=True` above, you will always get it loaded from the database with each query.*

Answer (score 0):

What you need in your subquery is a `GROUP BY` clause, so that the subquery contains the latest status for *every* product, rather than only having the latest status *overall* (which is what was happening in your subquery when you used `LIMIT 1`). Then you do your join and filter for only the status values that you want.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

subquery = (
    select(Status)
    .order_by(Status.created_at.desc())
    .group_by(Status.product_id)
    .subquery()
)

active_products_query = (
    select(Product.id)
    .join(subquery, Product.id == subquery.c.product_id)
    .filter(subquery.c.name.in_(["active"]))
)

print(session.execute(active_products_query).scalars().all())
```

Comment: How can I do a select on my `Status` and only group_by on `Status.product_id` ?
I tried your solution and got an `column "Status.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

(My Status model got many other columns that are not shown in my example)

Comment: The `subquery` contains all `Status` columns in it on its `c` property (and is what you're joining on), so you should pull out the `Status.id` from there into the second select, e.g. `select(Product.id, subquery.c.id.label("status_id"))`. You don't actually need that last `label()` call, but it's nice to add since in this case you have two columns called `id`